# Blanking an SAS HD without an SAS dock / server

Tags: hard-drive, sata, sas

I have some old SAS HDs which need to be securely deleted before recycling.  I don't have a spare SAS-equipped server, and my external hard drive dock is marked for SATA.  What tools can I use to securely delete these HDs?

Comment: I don't quite remember, but can't SAS disks be connected to a SATA controller? Or is it the other way around?

Comment: I believe they are electrically and signally separate protocols.  Physically, the connectors are the same.

Comment: They're indeed different protocols, but AFAIK the devices are supposed to be compatible in one direction anyway (implementing both protocols).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is correct, your motherboard is SATA, it won't talk to SAS drives. Your docking station might say SAS/SATA drive, but it won't work (see PS if that's the case).

I am afraid you will need to buy some cheap LSI 9211 HBA (from 30 usd) and plug that drive using appropriate cage or just using forward split cable. Only then you can have few options for secure erase:

```
- from BIOS of controller 
- 3rd party software: MHDD, CopyWipe, and hdparm
- storcli /cx[/ex]/sx secureerase [force]
```

*PS: - There are some "universal SATA" drive cages (e.g IcyDock MB994SP-4S or whatever else) having "sata" connector to connect cage to the controller. Cage states it accepts SAS/SATA drives. This never worked with SAS drives inside, regardless if I plugged them into SAS or SATA or SAS HBA, reverse or forward split cables, all tried. Shortly - forget "sata docks that accept SAS". The universal dock that works is actually SAS dock on SAS HBA or RAID ctrl, not vice versa.*